# Consolidating a Ruby Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm interning at a company right now, and I have a database that I connect to in order to get some specific data about our customers. The query is all worked out, the database is returning the data I need, but now I need to figure out how to consolidate the data into the necessary format. We are using Ruby 3.1.2 for reference.

This is the format that I receive from our database (the real data will be much larger, so I'm only using a small dataset until the logic is solid).

```
[{ "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>001 },
 { "product_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>001 },
 { "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>002 },
 { "product_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>002 },
 { "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>003 },
 { "product_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>003 },
 { "product_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>003 }]
```

When I get this data, I need to get a list of each distinct "customer_id" with a list of every "product_id" they have assigned to them. Example of what I need to get back below.

```
{001=>[1, 2], 002=>[1, 3], 003=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

I thought I had a solution with the line below, but it doesn't seem to work how I expected.

```
data.group_by(&:customer_id).transform_values { |p| p.pluck(:product_id) }
```

Comment: `{"001": ["1"],["2"]}` isn't valid Ruby code, could you update the expected output? Also, is there a reason you're not doing this with SQL if that's the source giving you the input?

Comment: You are correct, that was my mistake! I updated it to be what I actually needed. I don't know if you can tell I'm pretty new to Ruby code haha...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `#group_by` one might use `#each_with_object` to iteratively build the needed hash.

```
data.each_with_object({}) { |x, h| 
  h[x["customer_id"]] ||= []
  h[x["customer_id"]] << x["product_id"] 
}
# => {1=>[1, 2], 2=>[1, 3], 3=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Another way: `data.each_with_object(Hash.new([])) { |x, h| h[x["customer_id"]] += [x["product_id"]] }`

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
array = [{ "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>001 },
         { "product_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>001 },
         { "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>002 },
         { "product_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>002 },
         { "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>003 },
         { "product_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>003 },
         { "product_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>003 }]

array.group_by { |hash| hash['customer_id'] }
     .transform_values { |values| values.map { |value| value['product_id'] } }
#=> { 1 => [1, 2], 2 => [1, 3], 3 => [1, 2, 3] }
```

Comment: I marked the other answer as correct, but this actually does provide the exact same result with fewer line breaks!

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct in their own ways *but in my opinion code-readability should also always be considered* and considering that factor the accepted answer looks more nearer and my solution below is also based on the same logic with the only difference that I have moved out the string keys outside the loop because the string literal inside the loop should create, in each iteration, different String instances in memory for those keys.

```
array = [{ "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>001 },
         { "product_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>001 },
         { "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>002 },
         { "product_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>002 },
         { "product_id"=>1, "customer_id"=>003 },
         { "product_id"=>2, "customer_id"=>003 },
         { "product_id"=>3, "customer_id"=>003 }]

transformed_data = {}

customer_id_key = "customer_id"
product_id_key = "product_id"

array.each do |h|
  customer_id = h[customer_id_key]
  product_id = h[product_id_key]

  transformed_data[customer_id] ||= []
  transformed_data[customer_id] << product_id
end 

transformed_data
```